Buscar todos los resultados de una tabla relacionada con otra
tardes o noche a todos.
Veran, estoy usando mysql y php para esto, tengo 2 tablas (ejemplos)
TABLA A
----------------
|id| articulo  |
|--|-----------|
|1 |caja       |
|2 |baul       |
|3 |cofre      |
----------------

TABLA B
-----------------------
|id |id_art| fecha    |
|---|------|----------|  
|1  |1     |08/08/2024|
|2  |1     |15/08/2024|
|3  |1     |18/08/2024|
|4  |3     |02/09/2024|
|5  |2     |20/09/2024|
|6  |2     |05/10/2024|
|7  |2     |12/10/2024|
|8  |3     |01/11/2024|
-----------------------

De estas lo que quiero es hacer una consulta de todos los registros de la tabla A (limitada a 5 o 10 registros LIMIT 10), pero de el resultado de esto quiero igualmente mostrar los registros de la tabla B, como la fecha, resultado de los id de la tabla A, un resultado algo así:
|1 |caja
-----|1  |1     |08/08/2024|
-----|2  |1     |15/08/2024|
-----|3  |1     |18/08/2024|
|2 |baul
-----|5  |2     |20/09/2024|
-----|6  |2     |05/10/2024|
-----|7  |2     |12/10/2024|
|3 |cofre
-----|4  |3     |02/09/2024|
-----|8  |3     |01/11/2024|

Lo represento asi porque no se como saldria el resultado.
Actualmente lo solucione con 2 consultas anidadas en php pero quiero saber si hay una manera de hacer esto directamente en Mysql:
$cnstsqlcat=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM TABLA_A LIMIT 5");
while($mstrrcat=mysqli_fetch_array($cnstsqlcat))
{
   $id=$mstrrcat['id'];
   $art   =$mstrrcat['articulo'];

   echo "<h1>".$art."</h1>";

   $cnstsqlcat2=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM TABLA_B WHERE id_art = $id" LIMIT 3);
   while($mstrrcat2=mysqli_fetch_array($cnstsqlcat2))
   {
      echo "<h2>".$mstrrcat2["id"]."</h2>";
      echo "<h2>".$mstrrcat2["id_art"]."</h2>";
      echo "<h2>".$mstrrcat2["fecha"]."</h2>";
   }
}


Has buscado siquiera algo relacionado al tema de los JOINs??

Si claro, justamente ahorita estoy viendo ese tema sin embargo mi entendimiento del tema aun no me da como para esta situación particular, es por eso mi pregunta. Justamente quiero saber si hay alguna forma de realizar esto directamente en MySQL sin tener que hacer mi consulta anida en php o si lo mejor es la forma como lo hago actualmente

Lo tienes claro todo en el link que te pasé. LEE!!!

si, gracias, leere más y estudiare mas del tema, gracias

MySQL
En versiones recientes de MySQL puedes crear fácilmente un objeto json anidado usando JSON_OBJECT() y JSON_ARRAYAGG().
Para limitar y ordenar los registros de los grupos anidados puedes usar ROW_NUMBER().
Si observas la consulta de más abajo, al poner ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `af`.`id_art` ORDER BY `fecha` ASC) le decimos que nos cree grupos por la columna id_art y que ordene esos grupos por la columna fecha de forma ascendente. Luego, para poner un límite a esos grupos se lo indicamos por fuera con un WHERE seqnum <= 2, aquí estamos limitando los grupos a 2, eso lo puedes cambiar evidentemente, aquí pusimos un límite pequeño, para poder ver que funciona en nuestro set de datos, que no tiene muchas filas.
Esta sería la consulta:
SELECT
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'id_articulo',`id_articulo`,
        'articulo', `articulo`, 
        'filas',
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'id',`id`, 
                'fecha',`fecha`
            )
        )
    ) AS `datos`
FROM (
        SELECT 
            `a`.`articulo`,
            `a`.`id` AS `id_articulo`,
            `af`.`id_art`,
            `af`.`id`,
            `af`.`fecha`,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `af`.`id_art` ORDER BY `fecha` ASC) AS `seqnum`
        FROM 
            `articulo_fecha` AS `af` 
              INNER JOIN `articulo` AS `a` ON `af`.`id_art`=`a`.`id`       
     ) x
WHERE 
    `seqnum` <= 2 -- Aquí pones el total que quieres por grupo
GROUP BY 
    `id_articulo`, `articulo`
ORDER BY 
    `articulo` 
;

Por cada fila, esta consulta te arrojará un JSON con esta estructura más o menos:
{
    "articulo":"baul",
    "id_articulo":2,
    "filas":[
        {
            "id":5,
            "fecha":"2024-09-20"
        },
        {
            "id":6,
            "fecha":"2024-10-05"
        }
    ]
}

Si lo analizas, hay una propiedad articulo con el nombre del artículo, otra id_articulo con su id y otra filas que es un array de objetos JSON con los elementos de la segunda tabla. Habrá dos elementos por cada grupo porque así lo indicamos usando seqnum. Luego veremos en PHP cómo trabajar con esos datos.
Para terminar con la parte de MySQL, vamos a verlo en un fiddle completo. En Query #1 tienes la consulta, y al final del todo vienen los datos.
Schema (MySQL v8.0)
CREATE TABLE `articulo` (
   `id` INT PRIMARY KEY,
    `articulo` VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE `articulo_fecha` (
    `id` INT PRIMARY KEY,
    `id_art` INT NOT NULL,
    `fecha` DATE
);

INSERT INTO `articulo` (`id`,`articulo`) VALUES 
  (1,'caja'),
  (2,'baul'),
  (3,'cofre');
  
  
  INSERT INTO `articulo_fecha` (`id`,`id_art`,`fecha`)
  VALUES
(1,1,'20240808'),
(2,1,'20240815'),
(3,1,'20240818'),
(4,3,'20240902'),
(5,2,'20240920'),
(6,2,'20241005'),
(7,2,'20241012'),
(8,3,'20241101');


Query #1
SELECT
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'id_articulo',`id_articulo`,
        'articulo', `articulo`, 
        'filas',
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'id',`id`, 
                'fecha',`fecha`
            )
        )
    ) AS `datos`
FROM (
        SELECT 
            `a`.`articulo`,
            `a`.`id` AS `id_articulo`,
            `af`.`id_art`,
            `af`.`id`,
            `af`.`fecha`,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `af`.`id_art` ORDER BY `fecha` ASC) AS `seqnum`
        FROM 
            `articulo_fecha` AS `af` 
              INNER JOIN `articulo` AS `a` ON `af`.`id_art`=`a`.`id`       
     ) x
WHERE 
    `seqnum` <= 2 
GROUP BY 
    `id_articulo`, `articulo`
ORDER BY 
    `articulo` 
;




datos




{"filas": [{"id": 5, "fecha": "2024-09-20"}, {"id": 6, "fecha": "2024-10-05"}], "articulo": "baul", "id_articulo": 2}


{"filas": [{"id": 1, "fecha": "2024-08-08"}, {"id": 2, "fecha": "2024-08-15"}], "articulo": "caja", "id_articulo": 1}


{"filas": [{"id": 4, "fecha": "2024-09-02"}, {"id": 8, "fecha": "2024-11-01"}], "articulo": "cofre", "id_articulo": 3}




View on DB Fiddle

PHP
Usaremos json_decode() para mostrar los datos de cada fila.
El código quedaría así más o menos:
$sql='AQUÍ LA CONSULTA COMO MOSTRAMOS MÁS ARRIBA';
$cnstsqlcat=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
while($mstrrcat=mysqli_fetch_array($cnstsqlcat))
{
   $json=json_decode($mstrrcat['datos']);
    printf("id: %s \tarticulo: %s %s",$json->id_articulo,$json->articulo,PHP_EOL);

    foreach($json->filas as $fila)
    {
        printf("\tid: %s \tfecha: %s %s",$fila->id,$fila->fecha,PHP_EOL);
    }
}

El código mostrará algo así por cada fila:
id: 2   articulo: baul 
    id: 5   fecha: 2024-09-20 
    id: 6   fecha: 2024-10-05 

... Los demás artículos

Compatibilidad
Puede que si estás trabajando con una versión de MySQL antigua este código no funcione. En ese caso, si no puedes pasar a una versión más moderna, puedes escribir una consulta basada en GROUP_CONCAT y luego crear los grupos a nivel de PHP usando explode, o puedes crear el mismo resultado a nivel de MySQL, pero tendrías que hacerlo concatenando.
